# Split Text and number in a excel cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a cell text "`12-3 0000 9 FLY AIR Make MY Trip`"
and I want the output like `12-3 0000 9` into next cell and the next sequence cell "`FLY AIR Make MY Trip`".

```
Public Function SplitText(pWorkRng As Range, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String
    'Updateby20150306
    Dim xLen As Long
    Dim xStr As String

    xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng.Value)

    For i = 1 To xLen
        xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng.Value, i, 1)
        If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And pIsNumber) Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr)) And Not (pIsNumber))) Then
            SplitText = SplitText + xStr
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

`=SplitText(A2,FALSE)` into a blank cell to get the only the text.

Result as 12300009

`=SplitText(A2,TRUE)` into a blank cell to get the only the number.

Result  as "- FLY AIR Make MY Trip"

Comment: Is the format always NUMBERS (and "-") followed by TEXT

Comment: Please clarify the question

Comment: You have posted insufficient test data to reach conclusive solution.

Comment: "12-3 0000 9 FLY AIR Make MY Trip" i wanna to split into "12-3 0000 9" and "FLY AIR Make MY Trip"

Comment: @VinothNarayan can you post few more lines of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want to get the numeric first part, if your parameter `pIsNumber`is set true:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function SplitText(pWorkRng As Range, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String
'Declare ALL variables
Dim xLen As Long
Dim xStr As String
Dim i As Integer
xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng.value)
For i = 1 To xLen
    xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng.value, i, 1)
     If pIsNumber And InStr(" -0123456789", xStr) Then
        SplitText = SplitText & xStr   ' use ampersand "&" instead of "+"

     ElseIf Not pIsNumber And InStr("-123456789", xStr) = 0 Then
        SplitText = SplitText & xStr
     End If
Next
If pIsNumber Then SplitText = Replace(SplitText, String(3, " "), " ")
End Function
```

**Note**

Use ampersand "&" instead of "+" to join string values. BTW, don't forget to declare your variables and always use `Option Explicit` in the declaration head of your code module.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.but for text its coming along with ""000 FLY AIR Make MY Trip".for number it works perfectly

Comment: I tested above code again and it works for me. Suppose you omitted the blank space character " " in the comparation string of the first condition: `If pIsNumber AND Instr(" -0123456789", xStr) Then`, whereas the comparation string in the `Else ` condition  starts *without* blank.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Split`, check for text and then join again:

```
Function SplitText(Txt As String, Optional Number As Boolean = True)
Dim Arr, outarr() As String, I As Integer
Dim nbr As String, rest As String
Arr = Split(Txt, " ")
ReDim outarr(UBound(Arr))
    For I = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        outarr(I) = Arr(I)
        If Not IsNumeric(Left(Arr(I), 1)) Then
            ReDim Preserve outarr(I - 1)
            nbr = Join(outarr, " ")
            rest = Mid(Txt, Len(nbr) + 2)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next I
    SplitText = IIf(Number, nbr, rest)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text is in cell A2

Enter following formula where you need numeric portion (to be entered as array formula i.e. **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** and not just ENTER):

`=LEFT(A2,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(CHAR(ROW($A$65:$A$90)),A2,1),2^15))-1)`

If applied correctly Excel will show surrounding braces {}.

Then assuming you have above formula in cell B2, its result can be used as output to get the remaining text part like below:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"")`

If it works then you will not require VBA.

Comment: It returns me empty

Comment: @VinothNarayan I am not sure how you are using it. See attached file for implementation. [Example File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkzpdkub43az62m/stackoverflow_47154245.xlsx?dl=0)